# How to retrieve specefic div class in iframe tag?

Tags: jquery

I try to retrieve somethingclass2 class retrieving in an iframe tag with jQuery:

[image]

this code does not work for me:

```
 $("document").ready(function () {
  console.log($('iframe html body .somethingclass1 .somethingclass2'));
 });
```

thanks

Comment: what is efacebook?? or where is it in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your JS code and HTML code don't seem to correlate, this is only a guess but... is your iframe content coming from another domain?

If so, you can't get to the elements inside it. At least not without breaking browser security. If you could, it'd be an enormous security hole.

However, if the iframe content is from the [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) as the containing page, you can do

```
$("iframe.someiframe").contents().find("div.foo")
```

Comment: Hi Matti, thank you for your reply
I find this link 
http://huuah.com/jquery-and-iframe-manipulation
but I can not find this plugin on the site oficial
you have an idea

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work

```
$('#iframeID').contents().find('#someID').html();
```

please try if the above code is printing your html or not.